# What is the best way to search items by their name, description, tags, etc., in TypeORM (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql, typescript, e-commerce, typeorm

I'm trying to write a search function for an e-commerce website and products have multiple properties like name, description, tags, etc. I'm using Typescript, Mysql, and Typeorm in Back-end.

What is the best way to query items by their name, description, tags, etc., preferably with priorities in Typeorm? After a little bit of research, I found these possible answers:

1. `MATCH(name, description, ...) AGAINST ('${keywords}' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)` and adding `Fulltext` index to searchable columns like `name`
2. `Like %keywords%`
3. `REGEX`